# How to chain functions using reactor in python?

Tags: python-2.7, twisted, deferred, chaining

My code:

```
class Server(DatagramProtocol):

    SSDP_ADDR = "239.255.255.250"
    SSDP_PORT = 1900
    MS = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: {}:{}\r\nMAN: 'ssdp:discover'\r\nMX: 2\r\nST: ssdp:all\r\n\r\n".format(SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT)

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.Thread = None
        self.Thread = threading.Thread(target=self.startReactor)
        self.Thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.scanThread.start()

    def startReactor(self):
        """
        """
        reactor.callFromThread(self.sendMsearch)
        if reactor.callWhenRunning(lambda: None) is not None:
            reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=0)

    def sendMsearch(self):
        """ Sending M-SEARCH message
        """
        d = defer.Deferred()
        port = reactor.listenUDP(0, self, interface=self.iface)
        port.write(Server.MS, (Server.SSDP_ADDR, Server.SSDP_PORT))
        d = reactor.callLater(2.5, port.stopListening) # MX + a wait margin
        d.addCallback(self.cleanUp)

    def cleanUp(self, x):
        """
        """
        # stop thread and cleanup

    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, (host, port)):
        # doing some work
```

In above code i have to call cleanUp() after completion of port.stopListening.

And also how can i kill this thread

Is chaining possible here ?

If not then how to achieve my aim here.

Comment: Ugh... I think you may have some concepts confused here.  I can't imagine why you would try and call a def via `callFromThread` and then inside that try and do a `reactor.listenUDP` (it looks like you have some logic errors inside of `sendMsearch` as well) ... The primary point of twisted is doing async code that AVOIDS threading ... I couldn't directly answer you unless you explain why the threading stuff is in there (and what happens when you run it now).  In short though, `deferrers` are the method by which you schedule a def to run after the completion of something else.

Comment: @MikeLutz Actually i have another python program which is running my tool, and that calls this Server object

Answer (score 2):

The use of the reactor with respect to threads in this example is completely incorrect.  Twisted APIs are only safe to be called in the same thread as `reactor.run` is called.

In your example, `startReactor` and `sendMsearch` are called in different threads.  The former calls `reactor.run` and the latter uses other Twisted APIs.

If you want to integrate Twisted with other blocking Python code you may want to look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crochet